# How to enable Raspberry Pico's I2C0_IRQ and set a callback function using MicroPython?

Tags: i2c, pi-pico, micropython

I need to setup a Raspberry Pico as a I2C Slave device. I know how to do this, but I don't know how to eneble the I2C IRQ and set a callback function on it so I can be notified of the I2C events without keeping the CPU busy with continous pulling... I found some examples in C but I need in MicroPython.

[image]